# Spring store input from PUT in a list

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am trying to store the data I am receiving from a REST PUT call into a data structure. However, the data is cleared after the call is done. I do not want to use and database to store the values and I only want the data to be available during that session. I am new to Spring and I have set up the following file:

```
@RestController
public class TestController{
    List<Person> people= new ArrayList<>();

    @PutMapping(path ="/people", consumes = "application/json")
    public void addCar(@RequestBody List<Person> people){
        people.addAll(people);
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: We don't maintain state in REST call..!  It's Stateless. What do you mean by session here? Once you add people in people list, You should process it or save it in DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have the same names for field and method parameter.

When you invoke

```
people.addAll(people)
```

, you do not modify the field `people`, but only the local variable.

To fix your problem either rename the method parameter or write

```
this.people.addAll(people)
```

to access the field instead of local variable.

Comment: This fixed my problem. I didn't pay attention to this detail! Thanks.